# How is dimerization done?

Tags: bond

Nitrogen dioxide is dimerized to form dinitrogen tetroxide according to the equation
$\ce{2NO2 -> N2O4}$. How do two molecules of one compound fuse to form another?

Comment: I think you can answer your question easily. Draw the Lewis structures for NO2 and you'll see how the dimer is obvious solution to some problem.

Comment: The same way as any other reaction takes place?

Answer (score 2):

The electronic structure of NO<sub>2</sub> leaves an unpaired electron on the nitrogen. This is one of the reasons it is quite reactive. But it is also the reason why it can easily dimerise to N<sub>2</sub>O<sub>4</sub> as the two unpaired electrons in two molecules of the gas can pair up creating a weak bond. The dimer is favoured at low temperatures when the thermal energy isn't large enough to shake the dimer apart (I'm simplifying a bit). This is why the colour of the gas changes depending on temperature as the dimer is colourless but the NO<sub>2</sub> is brown.

Comment: This is very correct. However, when reading the questions it appears to me the person asking it (on a rather basic level) did not understand what the dimer would look like. There seems to be a misconception about the binding process, given the phrasing of "fusing". The crucial bit here is to understand that the atoms of the 2 nitrogen dioxide molecules are not broken apart and refused to form something new, but that the molecules stay intact and bind together. See also my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the confusion arises because you're unclear about what a dimer is. The molecules don't "fuse". They form a bond.

It's better to think of the dimer as $(NO_2)_2$ rather than $N_2O_4$.

Comment: I think it would be even clearer if you were to include the Lewis structure.